# Swift 4 : UITableView cellForRow crash

Tags: ios, uitableview

I can't understand what I am doing wrong. I have a UITableView called TblView_Categorie, what I am trying to do is get the cell at desired indexpath:

Here is my code:

```
let myRecordindex = IndexPath(row: myRecordcheck, section: 0)

let cell = tblViewcategorie.cellForRow(at: myRecordindex) as! categorieTVC
```

The problem is if MyRecordIndex is shown screen (no scrolling needed) everything working fine

If MyRecordIndex is not shown on screen (scrolling needed) I have this error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

If I manually scroll to the desired index and I enter the desired MyRecordIndex everything working fine

I tried to automatically scrolling using the code below: the scroll work but still same error

```
   self.tblViewCategorie.scrollToRow(at: myRecordindex, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.middle, animated: true)
```

Why I have this error? All I am trying to do is getting the cell at desired indexpath to change color, font, etc.

**// UPDATE cellForRowAt Implementation**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! categorieTVC
    if let categorieName = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath).categorieName{
        cell.setListeDesCategories(categorieName: categorieName)
    }
    return cell
}
```

// Update code and crash screen shot

[image: Crash and code]

Comment: show your cellForRow implementation

Comment: @MilanNosáľ  I update the code

Comment: Your code is very confusing to read. What is instance? What is type?  Please conform to the naming convention that variable names are *camelCased* and start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @vadian I did it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't explicit unwarp

```
 let cell = TblView_Categorie.cellForRow(at: MyRecordIndex) as! CategorieTVC
```

as cell my be not visible so it will be nil -> crash

try

```
 let cell = TblView_Categorie.cellForRow(at: MyRecordIndex) as? CategorieTVC 

 if(cell != nil)
 {

 }
```

Edit : scroll to the cell and dispatch after the cellForRow

```
let myRecordindex = IndexPath(row: myRecordcheck, section: 0)

self.tblViewCategorie.scrollToRow(at: myRecordindex, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.middle, animated: true)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0 )) {

 let cell = TblView_Categorie.cellForRow(at: MyRecordIndex) as? CategorieTVC 

 if(cell != nil)
 {

 }
}
```

Comment: the pb is how to make it visible beside scrolling? I tried scrolling by code using self.TblView_Categorie.scrollToRow  ==> the tableview scroll correctly but still crashing

Comment: what the crash says

Comment: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: I update the post with screen shot, and I do scrolling before and it is not working, thanks for help in advance

Comment: I did scroll and select and still crashing

Comment: use `if let`s instead of let optionals and checking for nils

Comment: @Sh_Khan well it work now by adding DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0 )). but I didn't understand why !. could you please explain?

Comment: @ColdLogic adding if let will resolve the crash but the cell return nil and that is wrong cz the cell exist.

Comment: Because the dispatch.after will wait until the scroll happens so the cell has a value that is not nil especially that you set scoll with animated:true

Comment: @Sh_Khan thank you Million time. I set animated to false and the pb is solved.

Comment: @Sh_Khan if I set animated to false no need the dispatch (tested), but I will keep animated to true with the dispatch.

Comment: animation is better with the dispatch , make user feel Good UX , keep going